# C++ std::locale("en") throws exception on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, c++11

On iOS, when I try to construct a C++ locale from a valid identifier, my program crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for en', reason: 'collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for en'

at this line:

```
std::locale loc("en");
```

This works fine on other platforms. And this is a valid locale identifier that exists on the platform (I tried with the identifier that comes from CFLocale).

I need a C++ `std::locale` for my program in order to format dates and numbers for example.

Maybe I need to include other libraries in the build?

I am using the latest XCode 9.4.1 and its included libc++, this runs on iOS 11.4.1. Other C++ features work fine in there.

Unfortunately, there is no way to list the available locales with portable C++, although all those I tried were listed in NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers

Comment: Different platforms are using different implementations of the standard library. Maybe the standard library on other platforms is falling back to "en_EN" if you insert "en". You should use proper locales as specified here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale Also this page is specifying legitimate locale codes for iOS https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: Check what kind of locale are available for your system, run command: `locale -a`. If your system is not configured to handle this locale this is the result.

Comment: @Geru according to that list `en` is a valid locale identifier. Also, OP mentioned that he tried locales that were listed in `NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers`

Comment: You cannot run locale -a on an iPhone. I tried with many locale identifiers, and the one that is given as the current one by CFLocale (the C++ iOS Foundation implementation).

Answer (score 5):

After researching this a bit, I understand that C locales are not included in the iOS builds. None.

My solution (because I want to format prices, times and dates from C++), it to ship the locales definition in my app. Unzipping them at first start, and setting the PATH_LOCALE environment variable to the newly created directory. (PATH_LOCALE is the BSD environment variable for the C library to locate locale definitions, not LOCPATH like on GNU/Linux)

PATH_LOCALE is the base path for the locale files, each locale is in a sub directory like:

fr/LC_TIME
fr/..
en/LC...

So I need sub directories, and iOS bundles do not support sub directories.

When you do

setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"en_US.UTF-8");

The C library looks for a directory called "en_US.UTF-8" in PATH_LOCALE.

```
NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

    NSString* localeDir = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/locale"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localeDir];

    if (!fileExists) {
        NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"locale" ofType:@"zip"];
        ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
        [zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath];
        [zipArchive UnzipFileTo:documentsPath overWrite:YES];
        [zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
    }
    setenv("PATH_LOCALE", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/locale", documentsPath] cString], 1);
```

This uses Ziparchive that you have to include in your project.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/ziparchive/